# Wrong rounding with float division

Tags: java, math, rounding, wrapper, long-integer

I was doing some arithmetic program today and I got a real funny result passing the result of float division to a setter :

```
class A {
 Float f;
 setF(Float f) {
    this.f=f;
    print (f)
  }
}

 Long x=7L;
 Long y=3L;

 print (x/y.floatValue() )

 a.setF(x/y.floatValue());
```

the result of the above pseudo program is something like this in the jdk 1.6

```
2.333333
2.0
```

any clue on where the round is performed?

Comment: That's not your real code.

Comment: give your compilable code.

Comment: Plesae post the code for your `print` method.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain your first condition i.e. `x/y.floatValue()' what you are doing is:

`long/ float` because you are taking `float value` from variable `y` from `floatValue()` method so according to its implementation, you will get y = 3.0F.

```
/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code Long} as a
 * {@code float}.
 */
public float floatValue() {
    return (float)value;
}
```

Your division will be `7L/ 3F` or say `7/ 3.0` which will give you the result as `2.333333`

Your second condition `a.setF(x/y.floatValue());` will also result `2.333333` check if you missed something or post your whole code.

[image]

As you can see in console header I am using JDK1.6

Answer (score 0):

It's a casting issue. Your `x` is still type long, whereas `y.floatValue()` is a float.

Both the divisor and the dividend need to be float or double to get what you want, so try for example, this:

```
    Long x=7L;
    Long y=3L;

    System.out.println((float) x/(float) y);
```

result -> `2.3333333`

Comment: And in fact, it would be a good idea to work with `Double` everywhere, instead of `Float` and `Long`.

Comment: both the print and the Set have the same operation Long/float there shouldn't be any difference and in fact it isn't, I tested it ... see may answer bellow

Comment: Right you are. Let's see his code for `print` method

Answer (score 0):

This rounding down to 2.0 does not happen, there may be a problem with how you wrote the code from that pseudo-code

I tested with this implementation

```
public class A {

Float f;

void setF(Float f){
    this.f=f;
    System.out.println(f);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long x=7L;
    Long y=3L;
    System.out.println(x/y.floatValue());
    new A().setF(x/y.floatValue());
}

}
```

This is the result

```
2.3333333
2.3333333
```